# Installing old MySQL server 4.1 on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: installation, mysql

how do I need to install mySQL server 4.1 on Ubuntu 11.04 server for a legacy app to run (it breaks on mySQL 5).

```
sudo apt-get mysql-server-4.1
```

doesn't work - "package is missing, obsoleted or available from another source".

**Background:**

I'm trying to migrate from a Windows Server to Ubuntu Server. I have a MS Visual Foxpro app connecting to mySQL server 4.1 on Windows.

Just trying to replicate that on Ubuntu for now.

So far, I've got it to the point where the app is already up and running from a remote machine (on mySQL 5.1). However, I have tested and verified that some functions don't work well and it is because of the difference in mySQL versions.

Invariably, someone would suggest that I tinker with the code. I can't do that yet as I didn't develop the app and am still negotiating for the source code.

In the meantime, my goal is just to get this thing to run in Ubuntu with as little hassle as possible and that requires mySQL server 4.1.

Thanks.

Comment: In your sudo command - install is missing ---

Comment: Note that MySQL 4.1 is not receiving security updates anymore, http://www.mysql.com/support/eol-notice.html

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an older post, but this page is one of the top links I found when searching and many of the links like this one are unanswered.  But there is a solution!  The YouTube link (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Ar5QszDYEs) shows the manual installation of MySQL 4.1.22 from source files in 6.06... but it still works in 11.05 with minimal alteration.  The steps I followed were:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall libncurses5-dev curl
curl --o mysql-4.1.24.tar.gz http://mirror.provenscaling.com/mysql/community/source/4.1/mysql-4.1.24.tar.gz
sudo tar -xvzf mysql-4.1.24.tar.gz --directory=/usr/local/src
cd /usr/local/src/mysql-4.1.24/
sudo groupadd mysql
sudo useradd -g mysql mysql
sudo apt-get install
sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/mysql
sudo make
sudo mkdir /usr/local/mysql
sudo mkdir /usr/local/mysql/include
sudo mkdir /usr/local/mysql/include/mysql
sudo mkdir /usr/local/mysql/lib
sudo mkdir /usr/local/mysql/lib/mysql
sudo mkdir /usr/local/mysql/share
sudo mkdir /usr/local/mysql/man
sudo mkdir /usr/local/mysql/mysql-test
sudo checkinstall
    y
    mysql-server 4.1.24
dpkg -l | grep -i mysql
sudo cp support-files/my-medium.cnf /etc/my.cnf
cd /usr/local/mysql/
pwd
bin/mysql_install_db --user=mysql
sudo chown -R root .
sudo chown -R mysql var
sudo chgrp -R mysql .
bin/mysql --version
bin/mysql_install_db --user=mysql
sudo bin/mysqld_safe user=mysql &
```

I hope this helps someone else too!

Comment: Excellent instructions, thanks! I'm upgrading a server from MySQL 4.1 to 5.1, and wanted to test things out on a dev machine before attempting anything with the production server. These instructions worked perfectly on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Heaps of thanks for this! I needed to use `sudo bin/mysql_install_db --user=mysql` (on the 7th last line) got errors on it not beeing able to create folders inside folders owned by root. Is that missing or was it just on my machine?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to install Mysql server 4.1 in Ubuntu.

1) This will install Ubuntu -(Your Sudo command didn't have "install"

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-4.1
```

2) If you wan to install PHP on Ubuntu use this

```
sudo apt-get install php4-mysql
```

3) After that creating Databases can be done by using PHPmyadmin -

```
mysqladmin create <databasename>
```

Comment: Sorry, missing out the install was just a typo...my actual command had install, and it didn't work.